# Выборка данных из базы

Tags: php

Есть FrontController

```
<?php

class FrontController
{
// Свойства класса
private static $_instance = null;
private $_db;
protected $_controller,
          $_action,
          $_params,
          $_body;

// Приватный конструктор для соединения с базой данных
private function __construct()
{
    try
    {
        $this -> _db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME , DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $this -> _db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo 'Коннект к базе';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}

// Метод, запускающий приложение
public function run()
{
    $url = !empty($_GET['action']) ? explode('/', trim($_GET['action'], '/')) : null;

    $this -> _controller = !empty($url[0]) ? preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $url[0]) . 'Controller' : null;  
    $this -> _action     = !empty($url[1]) ?preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $url[1])                 : null;

    $ctrl   = 'IndexController';
    $action = 'index';

    if(class_exists($this -> _controller))
    {
        $ctrl = $this -> _controller;

        if(method_exists($ctrl, $this -> _action))
            $action = $this -> _action;
    }

    $controller = new $ctrl;
    $controller -> $action();   
}

// Статичный метод
static public function getInstance()
{
    if(self::$_instance == null)
        self::$_instance = new self();
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function view($file)
{
    include_once VIEWS . 'header.php';
    include_once VIEWS . $file . '.php';
    include_once VIEWS . 'footer.php';

}

// Запрещаем метод "Клон"
private function __clone(){}
```

}

Он наследуется остальными контроллерами
    Создаю IndexController, который по умолчанию. Не пойму теперь одну вещь...
Как мне в других контроллерах получить доступ к свойству $_db, чтобы дальше составлять запросы к БД?
или я че-то не то написал? спасибо

Comment: А зачем вам $_db именно в контроллере? О_о

Comment: а как лучше сделать? недавно начал изучать ООП... MVC...

Comment: Работа с базой данных должна быть в модели, на то она и модель. А контроллер разговаривает с моделью и о существовании базы данных понятия иметь не должен.

Comment: Понял!!!!!!!!